# More efficent way to write this if statement? (Clean up code)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Originally, the idea was if the user had written a bio, show it on their profile. Otherwise, display a message.

```
<% if @user.bio.present? %>
  <p class="user-bio"><%= @user.bio %></p>
<% else %>
  <% if @user == current_user %>
    <p class="user-bio">Press the green edit button and write something interesting about yourself.</p>
  <% else %>
    <p class="user-bio">Sorry, this user hasn't written anything about themselves yet.</p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then I thought of a way to improve this feature. Instead of making the user navigate to their settings page (devise/registrations/edit), let them edit their bio straight from their profile page (users/show).

To do this, the bio will be an input field that just looks like text, but when hovered over or clicked on, the user can see they can edit the text.

So I made this mock up version below and added resources to my user controller. But I get an error with the last `else` tag. I'm new to rails (and ruby) and I think this code is quite messy. Could someone with more experience help me write a better if statement that solves the same problem. I need a cleaner solution.

```
    <% if @user.bio.present? %>
      <p class="user-bio"><%= @user.bio %></p>
    <% else %>
      <% if @user == current_user %>
        <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, multipart: true }) do |f| %>
          <%= devise_error_messages! %>
            <div class="input-group">
              <%= f.text_field :bio, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
              <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn-signin" %>
            </div>
      <% else %>
        <p class="user-bio">Sorry, this user hasn't written anything about themselves yet.</p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you have an end tag for your form_for.

Comment: He needs `elsif`...he's rendering two `else` statements.

Comment: Second else is for the nested if. It's not best practice, but there's nothing wrong with that syntactically speaking.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to nest a new `if` block inside of the first `else`.

Also, as @JoeC pointed out in the comments, you need a closing `<% end %>` for your `form_for`.

```
<% if @user.bio.present? %>
  <p class="user-bio"><%= @user.bio %></p>
<% elsif @user == current_user %>
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, multipart: true }) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="input-group">
      <%= f.text_field :bio, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn-signin" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p class="user-bio">
    Sorry, this user hasn't written anything about themselves yet.
  </p>
<% end %>
```

If you think this is still too much tag soup, you could put the form inside of a partial named `_form.html.erb` and render it. That way the main view template is focused on the logic of what to display rather than getting into the details of the form.

```
<% if @user.bio.present? %>
  <p class="user-bio"><%= @user.bio %></p>
<% elsif @user == current_user %>
  <%= render 'form' %>
<% else %>
  <p class="user-bio">
    Sorry, this user hasn't written anything about themselves yet.
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The last thing that I'll point out is that you may want to switch around the first and second `if` tests. The way your logic is laid out, the user would never be able to edit their bio after they've entered one.

Answer (score 1):

I agree 100% with Chris Peters. You can place the form code into a separate file called partial:

***app/views/YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME/_form.html.erb***

```
 <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), 
                        html: { method: :put, multipart: true }) do |f| %>

   <%= devise_error_messages! %>
     <div class="input-group">
       <%= f.text_field :bio, class: "form-control" %>
     </div>

     <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn-signin" %>
     </div>
 <% end %>
```

Some information about partials you can find here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

If you decide to follow Chris's advice, you can transform the code further:

```
<% if @user.bio.present? %>
  <p class="user-bio"><%= @user.name %></p>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'form' if @user == current_user %>
  <p class="user-bio">
    Sorry, this user hasn't written anything yet.
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Ruby If statements examples: [Great Ruby Shorthands For If…Then…Else](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ruby-shorthands-if-then-else/)

You can also consider using content tags as below:

```
<% if @user.bio.present? %>
  <%= content_tag(:p, @user.name, class: "user-bio") %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'form' if @user == current_user %>
  <% no_bio_msg = "Sorry, this user hasn't written anything yet." %>
  <%= content_tag(:p, no_bio_msg, class: "user-bio") %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this will help.